# What does this command about quantiles mean?

Tags: r

What does this command about quantiles mean?

```
Quintiles <- quantile(HX090, probs=c(0,0.20,0.40,0.60,0.80))

Quint_var <- cut(HX090, Quintiles)
```

what do I find with this command?
(I need the variable `Quint_var`)

Comment: I think you need `cut(HX090, quantile(x, probs=seq(0, 1, .2)), include.lowest=TRUE)`.

Comment: `cut` categorizes or bins a numeric variable. In your code, the break points are the 1st 20%, the 2nd 20%, the 3rd 20%, etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
?quantile
```

It opens documentation about quantile. Quantile refers to percentiles - for e.g. 0.99 means you are ahead of 99% of population.

On the right hand side under "Environment" tab, you would find `Quint_var`.

Comment: This is just a partial answer so far, you probably overlooked the `cut` part.